# How to write $\~{B}$

Tags: math-mode, accents

How to write $\~{B}$ in latex. During writing it shows that ! Please use `\mathaccent` for accents in math mode. Please suggest me.

Comment: ```\tilde{B}```

Comment: thank you ! Is there any package for using in case of symbol ?

Comment: You need no package, do you?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the mathmode or `$\textrm{\~{B}}$` or what tohez alread wrote.